# Converting mathematical LaTeX to basic text

Tags: math-mode, conversion

I am in need of a way to parse math equations written in latex to plain text. Is there any way to do this through a website or through a program?

For example, I need `\frac{b}{c}` to just be `b/c` and `\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(1\right)` as whatever the text equivalent is, perhaps lim as n->oo 1

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Well, it depends on exactly what you want in each case. The `\frac` case can done as `\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{#1/#2}`.

Comment: You know that all that *complicated* markup is used, because it would be rather difficult to put it as plain simple text.

Comment: It may possible by writing some internal conversion script by using some other possible scripting program like `Perl`, `Python`, etc. Eventhough it is difficult to write all `LaTeX` tags into simple text...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Sometimes copy-pasting from the PDF generated by LaTeX can actually give reasonable results. For the fraction it does not work (it is copied as b, newline, c) but the limit is copied as lim n→∞ (1).